# spring-boot logback.xml property depending on profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback

How can I get Spring Boot to set a property in my `logback.xml` based on the profile?

Here's what I tried:

I have an `application-default.properties` with:

```
log.dir=/var/log
```

And an `application-development.properties` with:

```
log.dir=target
```

And I want to pass this into my `logback.xml`:

```
<property scope="context" name="logDir" value="${log.dir}" />
```

Running with development profile `-Dspring.profiles.active=development` I get logback issue:

```
RollingFileAppender - Active log file name: log.dir_IS_UNDEFINED/My.log
```

Comment: What I usually do is have a separate logback.xml file for each profile and change the `logging.file` property for each environment. No idea if that would also be a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot (tested on 1.4.1), I would suggest:

application-default.properties:

```
logging.file=/var/log/My.log
```

application-development.properties:

```
logging.file=/target/My.log
```

logback-spring.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
     <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml"/>
  </configuration>
```