# Spring Boot: How to use custom logback.xml depending on current environment or spring profile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging

I have read the following two sources:

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/load-environment-configurations-and-properties-with-spring-example/

[spring-boot logback.xml property depending on profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37685773/spring-boot-logback-xml-property-depending-on-profile)

And I'm trying to do the following:

When I run my Spring Boot application with a specific spring active profile (`gradlew bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=sst`, which we use for single service tests), I need the application use specific logging configuration (let's say with specific log level or using logging that we could capture output of from the tests).

We do have a custom `application-sst.properties` file configured and that is picked up and works all right.

Is there a way for me to do something similar for the logback.xml - such as adding `logback-sst.xml` so that is used within the SST context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. If you need something a special configuration for tests only, there is a simple solution: Place `logback-test.xml` in `src/test/resources` and you're good to go.
2. Logback supports a concept of spring profiles that allow placing configurations for different profiles in the same file:

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<springProfile name="dev">
   <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   ... 
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
  </root>
</springProfile>

<springProfile name="staging">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     ...
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
</springProfile>

</configuration>
```

[Here](https://reflectoring.io/profile-specific-logging-spring-boot/) you can find the relevant tutorial

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly what I was looking for. Two things to note, related to my particular project set up: 1. My project ignored `logback-spring.xml` but was more than happy to use the standard `logback.xml`. 2. Don't forget to add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:$springBootVersion`, even though there is a whole bunch of other `spring-strarter-*` libraries available. The link is super useful

Answer (score 2):

Spring will only pickup profile information in your logback config when naming your config file "**logback-spring.xml**" instead of "logback.xml".

Inside the config file you can simply use your profiles like this example:

```
 <springProfile name="sst">
     <appender-ref ref="JSON_STDOUT"/>
     ...
 </springProfile>
```

You can even use negation for your profiles:

```
 <springProfile name="!prod">
     <appender-ref ref="JSON_STDOUT"/>
     ...
 </springProfile>
```